# What does "@" do when using NSLog function?

Tags: objective-c, nslog

Why do we need to put the "@" before the quotation mark when using NSLog()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@"..."` is a `NSString`.

`"..."` is a C string.

`NSLog()` takes a `NSString` as argument.

Comment: Yeah, basically you need to put @ in front of just about all string literals in Objective-C.  (Of course the "just about" is the catch, and once you get in the habit you get burned on the maybe 2% of cases where you shouldn't use it -- observe carefully whether the interface expects an NSString or a char*.)

Comment: (To elaborate a bit, NSString is an object type.  The actual char* (actually a unicode*) is stored within the object and "owned" by it, so you don't need to worry about changing string length when you modify it, placing a null at the end of the string, etc.)

Comment: So, `@"..."` = instance of the `NSString` class, a fancy class that can do all kinds of stuff with the Unicode strings they represent, `"..."` = not an object, but just a plain old array of 8 bit chars.

Comment: Yes, I think you have it!  (I wish other newbies caught on as quickly.)